# reuse *.resx(AngularJS) translation files in hybrid AngularJS/Angular 5 application

Tags: angularjs, angular, internationalization, angular-i18n, angular-hybrid

Hello I have AngularJS application which is using for internalization $translateProvider and WebResources.resx files :

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(['$translateProvider', 'sysSettings', 'ngDialogProvider',
        function($translateProvider, sysSettings, ngDialogProvider) {
            ngDialogProvider.setDefaults({
                closeByDocument: false
            });

            sysSettings.device = window['device'];

            if (window['device'] && ktmvPreference && ktmvPreference.preference) {
                sysSettings.webServiceURL = ktmvPreference.preference.webServiceURL;
                sysSettings.reportServiceURL = ktmvPreference.preference.reportServiceURL;
                sysSettings.onlineHelpURL = ktmvPreference.preference.onlineHelpURL;
            }

            $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);
            $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();

            var savedLanguage = localStorage.language;
            if (savedLanguage)
                $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage([savedLanguage]);
            else
                $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage(['en', 'fr', 'es']);

            var url = sysSettings.webServiceURL + 'api/GlobalResources';

            $translateProvider.useUrlLoader(url);
            $translateProvider.useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();
            $translateProvider.useMissingTranslationHandler('ktmvTranslationFail');
        }
    ]);
```

Now I am doing AngularJS/Angular5 Hybrid application. As mentioned in documentation Angular5 is using "i18n" for internationalization. "i18n" is using "*.xlf" files to keep translations.

So only way during AngularJS/Angular5 application keep both WebResources.resx and messages.xlf files with the same context ?

Is there any way to reuse WebResources.resx translation from AngularJS in AngularJS/Angular application?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be usefull for someone...
To be able to reuse */resx files in my AngularJS/Angular internalization I started to use ngx-translate library. 
This is how I implemented it : 
I created custom-translate-loader.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable()
export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any>{
    var apiAddress = "http://localhost:26264/api/GlobalResources/?lang=" + lang;
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.http.get(apiAddress, ).subscribe(res => {
          observer.next(res);
          observer.complete();
        },
        error => {
          console.log("cannot retrieve Global Resources");
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

then in my app.module.ts I imported

```
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CustomTranslateLoader} from "./common/loader/custom-translate-loader";
```

and in my NgModule i injected TranslateModule :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    FormsModule,
    routingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: CustomTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    ActivationComponent
  ],
  providers: [authServiceProvider,
    commonSvcProvider,
    BackgroundImageFactoryProvider,
    LanguageSvcProvider
  //  { provide: UrlHandlingStrategy, useClass: CustomHandlingStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

After this in my components (sign-in.components.ts for example) i am able to set up the language:

```
import {TranslateService} from "@ngx-translate/core";

export class SignInComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService) {

    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

  }
```